# 1 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure: }, that the pod didn't tolerate

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, k3s

My kubernetes K3s cluster gives this error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age   From               Message
  ----     ------            ----  ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  17m   default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector, 1 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  17m   default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector, 1 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

In order to list the taints in the cluster I executed:

```
kubectl get nodes -o json | jq '.items[].spec'
```

which outputs:

```
{
  "podCIDR": "10.42.0.0/24",
  "podCIDRs": [
    "10.42.0.0/24"
  ],
  "providerID": "k3s://antonis-dell",
  "taints": [
    {
      "effect": "NoSchedule",
      "key": "node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure",
      "timeAdded": "2021-12-17T10:54:31Z"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "podCIDR": "10.42.1.0/24",
  "podCIDRs": [
    "10.42.1.0/24"
  ],
  "providerID": "k3s://knodea"
}
```

When I use `kubectl describe node antonis-dell` I get:

```
Name:               antonis-dell
Roles:              control-plane,master
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=k3s
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=antonis-dell
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane=true
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/master=true
                    node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=k3s
Annotations:        csi.volume.kubernetes.io/nodeid: {"ch.ctrox.csi.s3-driver":"antonis-dell"}
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-data: {"VNI":1,"VtepMAC":"f2:d5:6c:6a:85:0a"}
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-type: vxlan
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/kube-subnet-manager: true
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip: 192.168.1.XX
                    k3s.io/hostname: antonis-dell
                    k3s.io/internal-ip: 192.168.1.XX
                    k3s.io/node-args: ["server"]
                    k3s.io/node-config-hash: YANNMDBIL7QEFSZANHGVW3PXY743NWWRVFKBKZ4FXLV5DM4C74WQ====
                    k3s.io/node-env:
                      {"K3S_DATA_DIR":"/var/lib/rancher/k3s/data/e61cd97f31a54dbcd9893f8325b7133cfdfd0229ff3bfae5a4f845780a93e84c","K3S_KUBECONFIG_MODE":"644"}
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Fri, 17 Dec 2021 12:11:39 +0200
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule
```

where it seems that node has a disk-pressure taint.

This command doesn't work: `kubectl taint node antonis-dell node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule-` and it seems to me that even if it worked, this is not a good solution because the taint assigned by the control plane.

Furthermore in the end of command `kubectl describe node antonis-dell` I observed this:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason               Age                  From     Message
  ----     ------               ----                 ----     -------
  Warning  FreeDiskSpaceFailed  57m                  kubelet  failed to garbage collect required amount of images. Wanted to free 32967806976 bytes, but freed 0 bytes
  Warning  FreeDiskSpaceFailed  52m                  kubelet  failed to garbage collect required amount of images. Wanted to free 32500092928 bytes, but freed 0 bytes
  Warning  FreeDiskSpaceFailed  47m                  kubelet  failed to garbage collect required amount of images. Wanted to free 32190205952 bytes, but freed 0 bytes
  Warning  FreeDiskSpaceFailed  42m                  kubelet  failed to garbage collect required amount of images. Wanted to free 32196628480 bytes, but freed 0 bytes
  Warning  FreeDiskSpaceFailed  37m                  kubelet  failed to garbage collect required amount of images. Wanted to free 32190926848 bytes, but freed 0 bytes
  Warning  FreeDiskSpaceFailed  2m21s (x7 over 32m)  kubelet  (combined from similar events): failed to garbage collect required amount of images. Wanted to free 30909374464 bytes, but freed 0 bytes
```

Maybe the disk-pressure is related to this? How can I delete the unwanted images?

Comment: Do you mean unwanted docker images? Check this https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/ but you may need to check what is using that much space on your root partition of the node. It may be container logs as they can occupy a lot of space if the apps are logging a lot.

Comment: [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/labels-annotations-taints/#node-kubernetes-io-disk-pressure) are reasons of why `node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule` taint is assigned. [Here](https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/efficient-node-out-of-resource-management-in-kubernetes-67f158da6e59) more details how it works. So check the comment above.

Answer (score 4):

Posting the answer as a community wiki, feel free to edit and expand.

---

`node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule` taint indicates that some disk pressure happens (as it's called).

> The `kubelet` detects disk pressure based on `imagefs.available`, `imagefs.inodesFree`, `nodefs.available` and `nodefs.inodesFree`(Linux only) observed on a Node. The observed values are then compared to the corresponding thresholds that can be set on the `kubelet` to determine if the Node condition and taint should be added/removed.

More details on `disk-pressure` are available in [Efficient Node Out-of-Resource Management in Kubernetes](https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/efficient-node-out-of-resource-management-in-kubernetes-67f158da6e59) under `How Does Kubelet Decide that Resources Are Low?` section:

> `memory.available` — A signal that describes the state of cluster
> memory. The default eviction threshold for the memory is 100 Mi. In
> other words, the kubelet starts evicting Pods when the memory goes
> down to 100 Mi.
>
> `nodefs.available` — The nodefs is a filesystem used by
> the kubelet for volumes, daemon logs, etc. By default, the kubelet
> starts reclaiming node resources if the nodefs.available < 10%.
>
> `nodefs.inodesFree` — A signal that describes the state of the nodefs
> inode memory. By default, the kubelet starts evicting workloads if the
> nodefs.inodesFree < 5%.
>
> `imagefs.available` — The imagefs filesystem is
> an optional filesystem used by a container runtime to store container
> images and container-writable layers. By default, the kubelet starts
> evicting workloads if the imagefs.available < 15 %.
>
> `imagefs.inodesFree` — The state of the imagefs inode memory. It has no default eviction threshold.

---

**What to check**

There are different things that can help, such as:

- prune unused objects like images (with Docker CRI) - [prune images](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/#prune-images).

  > The docker image prune command allows you to clean up unused images. By default, docker image prune only cleans up dangling images. A dangling image is one that is not tagged and is not referenced by any container.
- check files/logs on the node if they take a lot of space.
- any another reason why disk space was consumed.